# We can't say for sure when angels were created, but can we even say if angels were created at all?

Tags: old-testament

So over the summer I was on a mission trip and was thinking of angels protecting us while we were in some sketch situations, then later I began to ask myself where in the Bible does it say angels were created? The only evidence I have found is in Colossians 1:16&17..but then in John 1:3 it says "all things were made by him, and without him there was nothing made that was made". The end of the verse seems to imply that there are things that were not made. Am I misinterpreting that?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following two posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)  Personal interpretation doesn't really fall into what this site is meant for, but if you're looking for an official position from a denomination or group, we can help!

Comment: For tips on how to avoid this question getting closed (or to get it reopened if it does get closed) see [Tips for editing a question to make it suitable for re-opening](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1475/tips-for-editing-a-question-to-make-it-suitable-for-re-opening)

Comment: From Psalm 148 - "Praise him, all his angels! Praise him, all his hosts! [...] Let them praise the name of the Lord, for he commanded and they were created."

Comment: @JamesT - You should turn that into an answer.

Comment: -1 for not searching first and for question structure as pointed out by David.  However, welcome to the site!

Answer (score 7):

> Thou, even thou, art Lord alone; thou **hast made heaven**, the heaven of
>   heavens, **with all their host**, the earth, and all things that are
>   therein, the seas, and all that is therein, and thou preservest them
>   all; and the host of heaven worshippeth thee.
>
> Nehemiah 9:6

Also

> Praise ye the Lord. Praise ye the Lord from the heavens: praise him in
>   the heights.
>
> **Praise ye him, all his angels: praise ye him, all his hosts**.
>
> Praise ye him, sun and moon: praise him, all ye stars of light.
>
> Praise him, ye heavens of heavens, and ye waters that be above the
>   heavens.
>
> **Let them praise the name of the Lord: for he commanded, and they were created.**
>
> Psalm 148:1-5

And lastly, but probably the best answer:

> For by Him all things were created, both in the heavens and on earth,
>   visible and invisible, whether thrones or dominions or rulers or
>   authorities—all things have been created by Him and for Him. And He is
>   before all things, and in Him all things hold together.
>
> Colossians 1:16-17

Also about John 1:3 it is explaining that Jesus has always been there and that He is the Creator. All things were made by Him, and if He hadn't been there nothing would've been created.

Comment: +1. Good answer. For some interesting extrabiblical speculations on the nature of angels, see C. S. Lewis's space trilogy (especially the first book) and J. R. R. Tolkien's creation myth "The Music of the Ainur" in the Silmarillion. (I don't include the Frank Peretti on purpose. :-P)